# iOS UIImagePickerController & Camera Stabilization

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to ascertain whether camera stabilization will be used in a UIImagePickerController video record session. I've seen code for this in AVCaptureSession, but nothing shows up in the same way for UIImagePickerController.

If my device has camera stabilization capability (iPad Air 2, for example), will it be applied by default if I use the UIImagePickerController to record video? And if not, is there a way I can specify that it does? I don't want to have to switch to AVCaptureSession and lose the image picker, just to enable the stabilization.

Thanks